# Rails, scope, OR and joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I have a scope:

```
includes(:countries).where("profiles.sector = :sector OR advices.sector = :sector", :sector => sector)
```

It produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` INNER JOIN `advices` ON `advices`.`profile_id` = `profiles`.`id` WHERE (profiles.sector = 'Forestry_paper' OR advices.sector = 'Forestry_paper')
```

(yes I have country in my `Profile` and in my `Country` model)

Unfortunately, the `OR` seems to fail:

it doesn't render a profile having only the proper sector but no related advice. Thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are doing an INNER JOIN, so it requires that the profiles have a corresponding advice. Try the following instead:

```
Profile
  .joins("LEFT JOIN advices ON advices.profile_id = profiles.id")
  .where("profiles.sector = :sector OR advices.sector = :sector", :sector => sector)
```

This will also include profiles that have no advices.

Comment: thanks :) no better Rails way to write it? Moreover, how to chain the joins with LEFT JOIN?

Comment: it's ok, a mere AND makes it perfectly

Comment: There's no other Rails way to write the join. The joins method only works with inner join (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

Comment: You can always add additional joins calls: joins(...).joins(...) and you can combine conditions with AND or OR: "LEFT JOIN advices ON ... AND ... AND ...

Comment: >> There's no other Rails way to write the join << See my answer for a way to do this.

Comment: Okay, I guess I should restate: it's possible to write left joins in another way in Rails, but it's not pretty. I definitely prefer the explicit "LEFT JOIN" since it's clearer what you are attempting to accomplish. Using includes is meant to eagerly-load associations, not differentiate between inner and outer joins.

Answer (score 8):

You can do outer joins by specifying a where clause with a hash after the `includes`:

```
Post.includes(:comments).where(:comments=>{:user_id=>nil})
```

produces:

```
  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "posts"."id" AS t0_r0, "posts"."created_at" AS t0_r1,
   "posts"."updated_at" AS t0_r2, "comments"."id" AS t1_r0, "comments"."user_id" 
   AS t1_r1, "comments"."post_id" AS t1_r2, "comments"."content" AS t1_r3,
   "comments"."created_at" AS t1_r4, "comments"."updated_at" AS t1_r5 
   FROM "posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id" 
   WHERE ("comments"."user_id" IS NULL)
```

Ryan Bigg wrote a [helpful blog post about this](http://ruby.ryanbigg.com/post/1468788928/left-outer-join-with-arel).

**EDIT**

Be aware that this technique is more or less a side effect of the way Rails constructs the SQL for eager-loading associations. An explicit LEFT JOIN is more robust, as suggested in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Check out http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/ for more query goodness...</strike>

meta_where is now unmaintained: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_where

Rails 5 is introducing OR statements:
[Rails 5: ActiveRecord OR query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753168/rails-5-activerecord-or-query)

Comment: Updated the answer a bit.