# Rails 5: ActiveRecord OR query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

How do you do an `or` query in **Rails 5** ActiveRecord? Also, is it possible to chain `or` with `where` in ActiveRecord queries?

Comment: [May be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31096009/3444240)

Answer (score 243, accepted):

The ability to chain `or` clause along with `where` clause in `ActiveRecord` query will be available in ***Rails 5***. See the [related discussion and the pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052).

So, you will be able to do the following things in ***Rails 5***:

To get a `post` with `id` 1 or 2:

```
Post.where('id = 1').or(Post.where('id = 2'))
```

Some other examples:

**(A && B) || C:**

```
    Post.where(a).where(b).or(Post.where(c))
```

**(A || B) && C:**

```
    Post.where(a).or(Post.where(b)).where(c)
```

Comment: How can I get (A || B) && ( C || D). I tried   Post.where(a).or(Post.where(b)).where(c).or(Post.where(d)) but It produces as: (A || B) && C || D

Comment: @Imran i believe it would be `Post.where(a).or(Post.where(b)).where(Post.where(c).or(Post.where(d)))` this should create (a || b) && (c || d)

Comment: @Imran This doesn't seem to work for me: I get `ArgumentError: Unsupported argument type: #<MyModel::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f8edbc075a8> (MyModel::ActiveRecord_Relation)`

Comment: The equivalent to .or that takes a relation and produces an and is .merge. (A || B) && ( C || D) can be produced by Post.where(a).or(Post.where(b)).merge(Post.where(c).or(Post.where(d)))

Comment: @SiimLiiser where is `merge` coming from ? if its `Array#merge` that does not work for me, as I want a single query to be executed. and also being able to pass the whole thing as a relation

Comment: @MathieuJ. It's ActiveRecord::Relation#merge. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge

Answer (score 14):

We don't need to wait for rails 5 to use this `OR` query. We can also used it with `rails 4.2.3`. There is a backport [here](https://gist.github.com/bf4/84cff9cc6ac8489d769e).

Thank to [Eric-Guo](https://github.com/Eric-Guo) for gem [where-or](https://github.com/Eric-Guo/where-or), Now we can add this `OR` functionality in `>= rails 4.2.3` also using this gem.

Answer (score 8):

(Just an addition to the answer by K M Rakibul Islam.)

Using scopes, the code can become prettier (depending on the eyes looking):

```
scope a,      -> { where(a) }
scope b,      -> { where(b) }

scope a_or_b, -> { a.or(b) }
```

Answer (score 5):

I needed to do a **`(A && B) || (C && D) || (E && F)`**

But in Rails `5.1.4`'s current state this get's too complicated to accomplish with the Arel or-chain.
But I still wanted to use Rails to generate as much of the query as possible.

So I made a small hack:

In my model I created a *private* method called `sql_where`:

```
private
  def self.sql_where(*args)
    sql = self.unscoped.where(*args).to_sql
    match = sql.match(/WHERE\s(.*)$/)
    "(#{match[1]})"
  end
```

Next in my scope I created an array to hold the OR's

```
scope :whatever, -> {
  ors = []

  ors << sql_where(A, B)
  ors << sql_where(C, D)
  ors << sql_where(E, F)

  # Now just combine the stumps:
  where(ors.join(' OR '))
}
```

Which will produce the expected query result:
`` SELECT * FROM `models` WHERE ((A AND B) OR (C AND D) OR (E AND F)) ``.

And now I can easily combine this with other scopes etc. without any wrongful OR's.

The beauty being that my sql_where takes normal where-clause arguments:
`sql_where(name: 'John', role: 'admin')` will generate `(name = 'John' AND role = 'admin')`.

Comment: I think you can use `.merge` as the equivalent of &&, and build a proper tree to capture your parens. Something like... `(scopeA.merge(scopeB)).or(scopeC.merge(scopeD)).or(scopeE.merge(scopeF))`, 

assuming each of the scopes looks something like `Model.where(...)`

Comment: Check out this before using merge - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33501

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5 has ability for `or` clause with `where`.
For Example.

```
User.where(name: "abc").or(User.where(name: "abcd"))
```