# How to solve this syntax error in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Please help me to avoid this syntax error

I want to select first category with its children.

```
@categories=Category.where(categories: {id:[1]} && categories: {parent_id:[1]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
@categories = Category.where(id: [1], parent_id: [1])
```

This will give you all the categories with `id = 1` AND `parent_id = 1`.
Note that, you don't need the `[]` unless you want to include array of ids or parents ids. If you want for one id and one parent id only, you can just do this:

```
@categories = Category.where(id: 1, parent_id: 1)
```

Comment: Thank you it works, i tried this . how to write the same by or condition

Comment: In Rails 5 (which is not released yet, coming soon), we will have a feature where we will be able to chain `or` with `where` clause like this: `@categories = Category.where(id: 1).or(Category.where(parent_id: 1)`
But, this is not a part of Rails 4. See this post for some more example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753168/rails-5-activerecord-or-query

Comment: If you are on Rails 4.2, then you can try this gem: https://github.com/Eric-Guo/where-or
then you will be able to use that feature right now. Or, you can always use SQL to write queries using `OR`

Comment: You can do this way to use `OR`: `Category.where("id = ? OR parent_d = ?", 1, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find the Category record with id=1 and parent_id=1
the query should be:

**@category = Category.where(id: 1, parent_id: 1).first**