# Rails: Get two sets of ids in one call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm on rails 4 and using Postres 9.4. My code currently is like:

```
array1 = Model.where(some_condition1).ids
array2 = Model.where(some_condition2).ids
```

Is there a way to get the same results with only one database read? In the form:

```
master_array = <the solution>
```

and each element of master_array is of something like the form (where I know which conditions the id satisfied):

```
[id, some_condition1?, some_condition2?]
```

so I can quickly do:

```
array1 = master_array.select { |n| n[1] }.map { |n| n[0] }
array2 = master_array.select { |n| n[2] }.map { |n| n[0] }
```

Comment: use an OR in your WHERE

Comment: One database read but you still want it to end up in two separate Arrays?

Comment: clarified in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change the `SELECT` to return the `id` plus two custom columns that represent a boolean for each condition. This will populate adorable little models with only the attributes you asked for, but that respond to your custom column names as methods.

```
results = Model.select("id, #{some_condition1} as condition1, #{some_condition2} as condition2").where("(#{some_condition1}) OR (#{some_condition2}")
```

So then just check the columns you named `condition1` (or whatever you want to call them) and create your arrays based on the models that return true.

```
array1 = results.select(&:condition1).map(&:id)
array2 = results.select(&:condition2).map(&:id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on the complexity of your conditions, but for rather simple conditions I suggest you query with OR condition

```
results = Model.where('(some_condition1) OR (some_condition2)')
```

Then use [Array select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) to split into two arrays:

```
array1 = results.select {|itm| itm == 'something which covers some_condition1'}
array2 = results.select {|itm| itm == 'something which covers some_condition2'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you would want something like this:

```
Model.where(some_condition1).or.where(some_condition2).pluck(:id)
```

but that's not available, [yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753168/rails-5-activerecord-or-query).  You could use [arel_table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query) as well but what I would do is explicitly write the query.

```
Model.where('some_condition1 = ? OR some_condition2 = ?', condition1, condition2).pluck(:id)
```

Comment: upper record is available in rails 5

Comment: This will not result in two arrays, which (I believe) is what the OP wants.