# Rails 5: ActiveRecord AND followed by OR condition: A && (B || C)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My below active record statements are working fine:

```
Requirement.where(no: 0)

Requirement.yes_no.or(Requirement.where.not(parent_req: nil))
```

In Requirement model I have an `enum` field, which is working fine too:

```
enum response_type: { yes_no: 0, document: 1, interviewee: 2, sample_set: 3, brief_desc: 4 }
```

But when I combine above two statements:

```
Requirement.where(no: 0).where(Requirement.yes_no.or(Requirement.where.not(parent_req: nil)))
```

It is giving me error:

```
ArgumentError: Unsupported argument type: #<Requirement::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x005567c7c9bf88> (Requirement::ActiveRecord_Relation)
```

I expect the following query to be run:

```
SELECT `requirements`.*
  FROM `requirements`
 WHERE `requirements`.`no` = 0
   AND (`requirements`.`response_type` = 0 
    OR (`requirements`.`parent_req` IS NOT NULL))
```

Comment: Should that be a [`merge`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge)?

Comment: `Requirement.where(no: 0).merge(Requirement.yes_no.....)`

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine using `AND` (intersection), [merge](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) as mentioned by Tom Lord worked.

```
Requirement.where(no: 0).merge(Requirement.yes_no.or(Requirement.where.not(parent_req: nil)))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Rails 5: ActiveRecord OR query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753168/rails-5-activerecord-or-query)

`Requirement.yes_no.or(Requirement.where.not(parent_req: nil)).where(no: 0)`

put `where(no: 0)` at the end of ar query