# How to combine two variables (instances of the same object) into one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I use two instance variables like bellow in the view:

```
@conversations_user = Conversation.user(current_user.id)
@conversations_professional = Conversation.professional(professional.user.id)
```

I need to combine these two variables into one `@conversation_all`, and later order them by the time of the last message.

Is it possible to combine `@conversation_user` and `@conversation_professional` into `@conversation_all`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in SQL with the *or* query. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32753177/793330) for details but essentially.

```
@conversation_all = Conversation.user(current_user.id).or(Conversation.professional(professional.user.id))
```

If you already have them loaded on the ruby side, i.e. the SQL hit has been made, you can just combine the two with a [union operation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-7C).

```
@conversation_all = @conversations_user | @conversations_professional
```

Although, keep in mind that this would be done in ruby and less than optimal than doing it in pure SQL. However doing it in ruby, once you have the data in memory, doing it in SQL is moot.