# Rails 5 ActiveRecord - combine OR adn AND clauses

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I can't figure out the right syntax to use when including several models and using `AND` or `OR` clauses.
For example, there `Shop` model that `has_one` relation with `Address` model and `belongs_to` with `Country`.
How for example add `OR` to the below query:

```
Shop.includes(:address, :country)
```

Trying like this:

```
Shop.includes(:address, :country).where('countries.code'=> 'FR').and('counties.updated_at > ?', Date.today.days_ago(7))
```

raises the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `and' for #<Shop::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fb90d0ea3f8>
```

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753168/rails-5-activerecord-or-query/32754518) at SO, but in this case, I have to repeat the same `where` clause before each `OR` statement? - looks not so DRY :(
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't kick yourself... you don't need to use and at all, just string another where in:

```
Shop.includes(:address, :country).where('countries.code'=> 'FR').where('counties.updated_at > ?', Date.today.days_ago(7))
```

Comment: thank you, it generates `AND` clause, but what about `OR`?

Comment: This will work : `shops = Shop.includes(:country, :address).where('countries.code'=> 'BE').or(Shop.includes(:country, :address).where('countries.updated>?', Date.today.days_ago(10)))` but too verbose and DRY.

Comment: That looks as clean as you can get.. maybe split them both up into two different variables to make it look a bit nicer but I can't think of a quicker way than that

Comment: the 'OR' method works as you'd expect, and when you want an 'AND' just replace it with another 'where'

Comment: Ok, thank you, may be extract to a separate scope will make it DRYer...

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution if you need to add multiple `OR` clause to `AND` clause. To get around it, there is `arel_table` method that can be used as follows.
Let's say we have the following models

```
Shop -> has_one :address
Shop -> belongs_to :country
```

and we would like to find all the shops by country code and address `updated_at` or country `updated_at` should be greater then a date you pass in:

```
some_date = Date.today
countries = Country.arel_table
addresses = Address.arel_table

# creating a predicate using arel tables

multi_table_predicate = countries[:updated_at].gt(some_date).or(addresses[:updated_at].gt(some_date))

# building the query

shops = Shop.includes(:address, :country).where(countries: {code: 'FR'}).where(multi_table_predicate)
```

This will execute a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and here is `where` clause:

```
WHERE "countries"."code" = $1 AND ("countries"."updated_at" > '2019-03-12' OR "addresses"."updated_at" > '2019-03-12')
```

Sure, you can chain more tables and multiply `OR` conditions if you want.

Hope this helps.